# A-Frame Why mesh disappears at certain camera angle?

Tags: three.js, rendering, aframe, webvr

I am playing around with this A-Frame example on geometry instancing: https://cdn.rawgit.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing/153e6d9b128b807ebe606b1c65a3f43c09f7af61/index.html.

The issue is that when I put my Oculus rift headset and move my head around (90 degrees to the left or right), the mesh would disappear suddenly from the screen and VR headset.

Is there a way to prevent the mesh from disappearing.

Thank you!